# How to select column value for row in for statement?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Thanks for putting up with my n00bish questions in the past, I have another question on which i have done extensive research and found no answers.

I am trying to loop through rows in a table and select the value of a certain column, at this point all i want to do with that value is put it in a MsgBox, but my attempts have repeatedly failed.

```
Dim id As Range
Dim trtype As Range

set id = Activesheet.Range("Table1[Column1]")

For Each r In id
    r.Select
    Set trtype = .Range(Cells(.ActiveRow, "Column5"))
    MsgBox trtype.Value
Next r
```

This returns "Type Mismatch" with the row
`trtype = .Range(Cells(.ActiveRow, "Column5")` highlighted.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: `.Range(Cells(.ActiveRow, "Column5"))` can only work within a `With` block. Is there one? Also you need to use set when assigning objects: `Set trtype = .Range...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing the following:

```
For Each r In id
    r.Select
    trtype = Selection.Text
    MsgBox trtype
Next r
```

Thanks for getting me on the right track with the answer about set, that led me to a discussion of when to use set and the discovery that it was only for objects and that strings had to be set with `.Text` Not `.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out the word SET in the line:

```
trtype = .Range(Cells(.ActiveRow, "Column5"))
```

trtype is an object variable (ie one which points to a built-in Excel object).  The VBA rule is that you must use SET to assign it.

For many years this was my most common VBA error!

Comment: That solved the mismatch error, but it now says "Invalid or unqualified reference" and selects the `.ActiveRow`, do i need to activate my selection?

Comment: All cells have got a VALUE property, and that's what I normally use.  If you do want to get at the range itself, you need:

SET trtype = ActiveCell
MsgBox trtype ActiveCell.Value

However, you don't need to select the cell to work with it (and indeed doing so will significantly slow down your macro).  Instead, you could just use:


MsgBox r.Value